# Sending push notification to Chrome

Tags: android, ios, node.js, push-notification, service-worker

I am writing a simple Single Page Application that allows people to be chat. The app will mainly be used on mobile devices (mainly Android, but some iOS although Android is the main focus).

In terms of notifications, I was leaning towards https://github.com/primus/primus . However, my main issue is that I *need* notifications to be delivered even when the users have their mobiles off -- or are not visiting the specific page.

So, I am also looking into service workers and push notifications -- and am wondering if I should use those for *everything* and forget about Primus.

So... questions:

Questions:

- Should I go for a hybrid architecture (Primus + Push notifications using web workers), or shall I stick with one?
- Going the Service Worker's way, how would I go about it without using Firebase etc.? That is, what would the service worker look like? And what would the push code (node/server and client side) look like?
- Again in terms of service workers, if the user restarts their phones, or for whatever reason the service worker isn't running on their client, is there a way for the server to know this? (in that case, I'd send an SMS or an email...)
- OR, is it even possible for a mobile site to get the device ID viewing the page, and go for a mobile push architecture instead?

Answer (score 0):

> Should I go for a hybrid architecture (Primus + Push notifications using web workers), or shall I stick with one?

You should not build an RTC system on the top of the Web Push API. That's not the intended purpose of Web Push but offering a mechanism of notifying the user about [timely events](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/push-notifications/).

You could use Web Push when you can not establish an RTC connection for getting the user to reopen your SPA and reconnect.

> Going the Service Worker's way, how would I go about it without using Firebase etc.? That is, what would the service worker look like? And what would the push code (node/server and client side) look like?

If you want to receive Web Push notifications in Android, you can not avoid Firevase since you need GCM (which now is Firebase Cloud Messaging).

> Again in terms of service workers, if the user restarts their phones, or for whatever reason the service worker isn't running on their client, is there a way for the server to know this? (in that case, I'd send an SMS or an email...)

Honestly, I don't know. But you could build your own ack system. If you don't receive an ack in a reasonable time window you could assume the device is not receiving the notification.

> OR, is it even possible for a mobile site to get the device ID viewing the page, and go for a mobile push architecture instead?

Perhaps with specific browser extensions but not in a standard and cross-browser supported way.